# Creating speeding stripes via Texture-Mapping

Tags: texture-coordinates

Community,

I already have a few years of experience with blender, but one functionality I could never get my head around was mapping. I've done my first [UV-maps for textile models](https://studiocool.de/rover-loungechair/), but I can't solve the following problem:
I'm trying to achieve this animated 'speedstripe' effect: (first video)

[OLAY ProX on Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/93164623/OLAY-ProX)

I've tried to use a half-circle backplane and moving and rotating an arbitrary gradient texture but couldn't get the same look. The reference looks like a circular or planar map is being manipulated in some way.

Can you point me in the right direction on what to google or how I need to orient my gradient-texture to achieve this effect?

Any help or reference is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this - if you enter #frame in the Value Node box where I've indicated, the value will change with the frame number when you animate. After that I just added some math nodes to slow down the process and give it a back and forth motion (sine node). You can omit this if you want. The other math nodes are just to give an the values different offsets for the phase offset and distortion respectively.

[image: Slide]

Here is an example of it in action - pardon the quantization and overall crappy look of the gif - I had to take a really short clip and compress it to make the file size acceptable by this page. The real effect looks much better.

[image: Slide2]

Comment: Sorry. I just noticed that in my screenshot I am using "Object" texture coordinates - that was just because I had to mess around to get the best screenshot - it works just fine, and in fact, better, with UV coordinates.